# IE9 not recognizing border-radius

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I cannot get IE9 to recognize my CSS border style: `border-radius: 10px;`. I also tried using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`, but it just messes up my background (it cuts a piece from my background at the bottom).

```
<html>
<style>
.outer{
    background: url('http://v4m.mobi/php/i/images/grey_background.jpg');
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;


.inner{
margin: 0 auto;
border: 3px solid #444444;
vertical-align: middle;
-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;  /* <-- This line */
background-color: #999999;
}

.inner td{
width: 213.33px;
height: 340px;
}
</style>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" style="margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; border: none">

<div class="outer">
<div style="padding-top: 5%;"></div>
<table class="inner" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff">referferf$<br/>dcsdcsd</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I meant, I also tried using the - meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" tag, it did work, but it just messes up my background layout. I could get border-radius to work earlier, but for some reason it doesn't mix with my code

Comment: Your page is missing a doctype.

Comment: @DextrousDave surround inline code with backticks. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: IE9 supports `border-radius`.

Comment: try meta tag "IE=8" `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` also view your output in compatibility mode(Tools->compatibility view).

Comment: not sure if it will work for border radius. But there is the -ms prefix for some things. try '-ms-border-radius: 10px;' not sure it will work tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is to use standards rendering mode - add `<!doctype html>` or `X-UA-Compatible` header. If it broke some other parts of your website, it just means you should rewrite your code because it's optimized for IE's quirks mode.